# What's the best way to make a recursive call with a SWITCH parameter?

Tags: powershell, switch-parameter

In the below example I've got an `IF` statement to determine which parameters send to `Demo` when called recursively.  If `$y` were a boolean value rather than a switch I could simply call `Demo -x $x -y $y`; but as a switch that's not a viable option.

```
function Demo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [int]$x
        ,[switch]$y
    )
    process {
        $x--
        if ($x -gt 0) {
            "$x - $($y.IsPresent)"
            if($y.IsPresent) {
                Demo -x $x -y
            } else {
                Demo -x $x
            }
        }
    }
}
Demo 10 -y
Demo 10
```

**Question**

Is the above the correct way to handle this scenario, or does a cleaner option exist?

Comment: You can send booleans to a switch....`-y:$true` for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force a switch parameter by calling it like this: `-Switch:$true` (redundant in most cases) or `-Switch:$false` so for your example:

```
Demo -y:$y
```

By the way in this example, you could also use splatting:

```
Demo @PSBoundParameters
```

But your post is clearly a MVCE so this may not apply to what you're actually doing, or may need modification, especially [if you have default values for some parameters](https://www.briantist.com/how-to/splatting-psboundparameters-default-values-optional-parameters/) (full disclosure: my blog).

Comment: `-switch:$true` is not always redundant. It is possible to make a switch parameter default to $false, in the same way you can give other parameters defaults.

Comment: @user2460798 that's true but it would be very bad form to do so (in a function definition anyway, in `$PSDefaultParameterValues` it would be fine). It's a good point though so I did edit slightly.